# Missing step in the derivation of the compressible Euler equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vector-fields, calculus

My reader wants to derive the Euler equations. It starts with the continuum version of momentum conservation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_Vd\mathbf r \rho_m(\mathbf r,t)=-\int_{\partial V}d^2\mathbf S\,\cdot\mathbf u(\mathbf r,t)\rho_m(\mathbf r,t)\mathbf u(\mathbf r,t)+\mathbf F(\mathbf r,t).$$
Here $\rho_m=m\rho$ is the mass density (and $m$ the mass per particle), $V$ is a fixed volume, $\partial V$ is the boundary of said fixed volume, $d\mathbf S$ is an outward facing differential normal vector and $\mathbf F$ is the total force. Using some steps this can be written as the Euler equations:
\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\rho_m\mathbf u)=-(\mathbf u\cdot\nabla)\rho_m\mathbf u-\rho\nabla V(\mathbf r)-\nabla p\tag{1}\end{align}

My question is about the derivation for the first term on the right hand side of the equation. Using Einstein notation this term becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial V} d^2S_iu^iu^j\rho_m=\int_Vd^3r\ \partial_i(u^iu^j\rho_m)
\end{align}
The term inside the integral can be written as
$$\partial_i(u^iu^j\rho_m)=\underbrace{u^i\partial_i(\rho_mu^j)}_{(\mathbf u\,\cdot\nabla)\rho_m\mathbf u}+\underbrace{\rho_mu^j\partial_iu^i}_{\rho_m(\nabla\cdot\mathbf u)\mathbf u}$$
If the second term where zero I would have the right expression but in the text it doesn't say we can assume incompressibility yet. Does anyone know how I would get equation (1)?

Here's a screenshot of the reader for reference

[image]

Comment: The left side of your first differential equation looks incorrect.  The partial derivative of u with respect to time should be present there, not rho.

Comment: @ChetMiller Good catch, thanks